# Trying to build a calculator in java but I keep getting the .class error

Tags: java, .class-file, java.lang.class, js.class

I just started a java class that my summer program was offering and we were tasked with creating a simple calculator. I have all the different cases created and all the variables accounted for but for some reason I keep getting a .class error and I have no clue what it is all I know is it comes from:

cases(int fnum, int snum, String op);

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class day1{
   public static void main(String [] args){
      cases(int fnum, int snum, String op);
   }
   public static void input(){
      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

      int fnum, snum;
      String op;

      System.out.println("Enter first num: ");
      fnum = userInput.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter second num: ");
      snum = userInput.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter operation: ");
      op = userInput.next();
  }

  public static void cases(int fnum, int snum, String op){
      input();
      switch(op){
      case "+":
         System.out.println(fnum + snum);
         break;
      case "-":
         System.out.println(fnum - snum);
         break;
      case "*":
         System.out.println(fnum * snum);
         break;
      case "/":
         System.out.println(fnum / snum);
         break;
      default:
         System.out.println(fnum % snum);
         break;
      }

  }

}
```

Comment: Post the .class error you're getting? You could also do the input in main and then call `cases ()` with your parameters, or at least declare them in `main()`

Comment: @DrZoo                       day1.java:8: error: '.class' expected
       cases(int fnum, int snum, String op);

Comment: Also I'm trying to keep as many things out of main as I can. That's the reason why I created a separate class to hold the user input. Something my teacher asked for

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to look like this.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class day1{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int fnum = 5;
        int snum = 5;
        String op = "";
        input(fnum, snum, op);
    }
    public static void input(int fnum, int snum, String op){
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter first num: ");
        fnum = userInput.nextInt();

        //rest of your code

        cases(fnum, snum, op);
    }
    public static void cases(int fnum, int snum, String op){
           //your code
    } 
}
```

You needed to declare your variables then pass them into your function so your cases function can also reference them. I think what your teacher means by keep things out of main is don't do your input and cases code inside of `main()`. Instead your teacher probably wants you to use functions, like you're doing.

Comment: Thank you now my .class error is out of the way but for some reason I don't get an answer for my operations. I input the numbers and the operation sign but after that the program completes as though its not doing anything with the print statements underneath each case